# How to make enemy circle player when in range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a propably simple script. As I am new to coding and stuff, there is a high chance that my code looks horrible.

Okay, so here's the thing: 
I have an enemy triggered, and only spawning when the player get's near a certain point. Then the Enemy has to follow the player, doesn't matter where he is, and keeping a certain range of 3 units. 
To this point. Everything works fine.

Now, what doesn't seem to work is, that I need my enemy to "orbit" around my player, when he is in a certain range (3) and only then.
For now, it's orbiting right from the start...what did I miss??

Thats my code so far:

```cs
public Transform mTarget;
float mSpeed = 10.0f;
const float EPSILON = 3.0f;
public float speed;

void Start()
{
    OrbitAround (); 
}

void Update() {
    transform.LookAt (mTarget.position);
    if ((transform.position - mTarget.position).magnitude > EPSILON)
        transform.Translate (0.0f, 0.0f, mSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OrbitAround() {
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mTarget.transform.position) < 3) {
        transform.RotateAround (mTarget.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }       
}
```

Big Thanks in advance, if anyone can help me out.

Cheers,

Comment: if `Update` is using `mTarget` as destination, why `OrbitAround` is using `Player.transform`? Also, where are you calling `OrbitAround`? And finally, the follow will stop at `EPSILON`, 3, but your orbit code checks for a distance lesser than 2.

Comment: i guess i could just delete the "Player" and use mTarget .transform?
Edited the Start (), guess it's supposed to be called there?

Comment: "guess"? You have written the code, you should know what each line does, not "guess" what it does...

Comment: well, yep, deleted. mTarget and Player are actually the same. So there was no sense in there.

Comment: This won't work; take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html (basically start is called ONCE and not afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

As @Zibelas said, the Start function is only once.

The Unity documentation states:

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any of the Update methods is called the first time.

So try putting the call to OrbitAround() in the Update function and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Well, didn't really fixed this problem exactly, but I found a way to work around it.

I just enabled the script to orbit around the target, when the enemy get close to it and disabled it, when the player goes away again.

```
void Update (){

        if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, mTarget.transform.position) < 15) {
            script.enabled = true;
        }
            if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, mTarget.transform.position) >15) {
                script.enabled = false;
        }
```

Still, thanks for the comments and information, guys.